# In duplicate-proposal emails, please check if I follow both first

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51, email, closed-proposals

I just got two similar emails from Stack Exchange. One goes:

> I am contacting you because you recently supported a proposal to create a Russian language Stack Exchange site (Russian Language & Usage - students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Russian language. ).
>
> Another closely-related Russian language proposal was closed in support of one, leading proposal.
>
> **If you are not currently following the proposal**
>
> Russian Language & Usage
>
> please click on that link to commit to it. It is doing very well and, with our combined support, a Russian language site can be created soon!

Emphasis mine. I was following the linked proposal in both cases. There is no reason to let the user parse the conditional statement when SQL could do it. Please only send these emails to users who are not following the new proposal.

Comment: I got the same email and I'm still not sure which proposal got closed. The email makes it read like a proposal got closed as a duplicate of itself. Were there really two proposals with the exact same name?

Comment: @Anna: At least regarding the Russian one, it's because they have the same name. The one that stays very recently changed name from "English-Russian Exchange" to [Russian Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10848/english-russian-exchange), and its scope got changed completely. The one that got closed was a "real" [Russian Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26012/russian-language-usage).

Comment: @Anna: Well, changing names just before sending the emails doesn't :)

Comment: The proposal was reworded *before* I realized there were *two* of them. That's the only anomaly that makes this merger *appear* so unusual. This is an extraordinarily unusual set of coincidences and doesn't warrant a feature which excludes a group of users from the email, as I outlined in my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

If we make a significant course correction to a proposal, it sounds reasonable to let the supporters know about it.

If you're *only* following the closed proposal, the link in the email directs you to the new proposal to follow.

If you're following *both* proposals, at least you're being notified "Hey, look; Your proposal just got a big boost. Two proposals you were following are now one!" Maybe you'll want to move some of your example questions from the closed proposal. Who know? The purpose here is to let everyone know what's going on.